# r function called by value instead of reference on a data.table that had a names() <- call beforehand

Tags: r, data.table, pass-by-reference

We know `R` has 4 datatypes that provide mutable objects or pass by reference semantics, and `data.table` is one of them. ([Best Coding Practices for R chapter 11](https://bookdown.org/content/d1e53ac9-28ce-472f-bc2c-f499f18264a3/reference.html#for-pass-by-reference))

In the following piece of code, first I create a function that will add a variable to the input data.table. As `data.table` are passed as by reference, this should change the data.table sent into the function and add a column.
I create two `data.table`s that are basically the same, I change their column names to upper case with different methods and then pass them into the function but the objects are not the same after the function!

```
library(data.table)


f <- function(x){
  x[,newvar:=2020]
}

dt1 <- data.table(a=1:20,b=21:40)
dt2 <- data.table(a=1:20,b=21:40)


names(dt1) <- toupper(names(dt1))
setnames(dt2,toupper(names(dt2)))

names(dt1)
class(dt1)
str(dt1)

names(dt2)
class(dt2)
str(dt2)

f(dt1)
f(dt2)


names(dt1)
names(dt2)
```

The two objects are different now. `dt1` does not contain the `newvar`!

Why?

Comment: Check out `truelength(dt1); truelength(dt2)` after changing the names. `names<-` removes the over-allocation that is needed to add columns by reference. Don't use it with data.tables.

Comment: @Roland what is the over-allocation and how can I check it? For this specific function I have `setnames` so there is no worry, but I like to be able to check for other functions and be sure.
The result of truelength is different after the name change: 2 and 1024! What does it mean in this context?

Comment: Over-allocation means that memory is allocated for more columns than currently exist. Data.tables are pretty much always over-allocated. You can check that by comparing the return values of `truelength(DT)` and `length(DT)`. Maybe read `help("truelength")`.

Comment: I read more on this, and oddly it seems that ``names<-.data.table``  of the data.table package causes the useful warining from data.table dissapear. When I rewrite it removing x = shallow(x) line, It gives me this waring running function f on dt1 (cont. in next comment):

Comment: In \`[.data.table\`(x, , \`:=\`(newvar, 2020)) :
  Invalid .internal.selfref detected and fixed by taking a (shallow) copy of the data.table so that := can add this new column by reference. At an earlier point, this data.table has been copied by R (or was created manually using structure() or similar). Avoid names<- and attr<- which in R currently (and oddly) may copy the whole data.table. Use set* syntax instead to avoid copying: ?set, ?setnames and ?setattr. If this message doesn't help, please report your use case to the data.table issue tracker so the root cause can be fixed or this ...